# How to delete lambda deployed using serverless framework once the feature branch is merged to master?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I have deployed a lambda using serverless framework. I want to clean up the lambda once the feature branch is merged to master.

Answer (score 2):

Use `serverless remove`.
You can do it automatically as a [Git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks @Ronyis. I will try that.